# Как происходит сложение дробных чисел в Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, float, ieee-754

Почему при сложении 3.3 + 3.3 + 3.3 Python выводит 9.89999999999999 и если ли варианты это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 3.3 + 3.3 + 3.367812391
print(a)
b = round(a, 5)
print(b)
```

Это делает встроенный метод round, второй параметр указывает, до скольких знаков после запятой округлить.